# htaccess rewrite-rule creates endless loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my-site\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub-dir(/)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub-dir/ [R=301,L]
```

The rule is supposed to mean:

If someone goes to www.my-site.com and DOESN'T add /sub-dir, redirect them to www.my-site.com/sub-dir/

The first step works. Means, when entering www.my-site.com/ I get redirected to www.my-site.com/sub-dir/

But then an endless loop occurs and the redirect doesn't stop.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, a bunch of them. I added this rule as the first of the rule-set, though. I might add, it's a processwire-site

Comment: and even if I remove the other rules, the loop persists

Comment: No, there's no .htaccess there. The directory doesn't exist physically, the cms handles the output when detecting sub-directories. And without the rewrite-rule, the page is being loaded without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my-site\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+sub-dir[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /sub-dir/ [R=301,L]
```

Due to other rules below this rule `REQUEST_URI` is changing to something else (maybe `index.php`) and causing this negative `RewriteCond` to succeed again.

`THE_REQUEST` on the other hand, doesn't change after application of other rewrite rules.

Comment: That looked promising - but it's not working either... :(

Comment: correction: it almost works - but it seems the cms gets confused and doesn't load any css/js files... but I'm getting closer...

Comment: For css/js etc.  add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`